# How to get Resource Hacker to work on .rc source files

Tags: c++, resources

I'm trying to use Resource Hacker to edit WIN32 dialogs, since the free version of Visual Studio doesn't support resource editing.  I used to use the Borland resource editor when I was on Windows XP, but can't get that to work on Windows 7.

Anyway, when I open a `.rc` file in Resource Hacker, it just shows the source.  Presumably, I need to compile this before I can start editing resources.  But all my control ID's are defined (with `#define`) in an external `.h` file, and the `#include` directive to pull that in doesn't work - either with a relative path or an absolute path.  If I copy the `#define` statements into my source file, Resource Hacker can process them.

I tried opening the pre-compiled `.res` file with Resource Hacker, and that works - allowing me to edit resources, and all.  But of course, all the resource id's are shown with their integer values.  So theoretically, I could edit resources that way and then copy/paste the results into the original `.rc` source file - but surely this isn't how the tool was meant to be used...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use it wrong. ResHacker was designed to modify the resources of a PE32.

The two answers to this SO question:
[resource (.rc) file include header ignores visual studio project include paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12367627/resource-rc-file-include-header-ignores-visual-studio-project-include-paths) should help you compile your RC files.

Good luck!

Comment: So, I guess ResHacker isn't the tool I want.  Your link has to do with getting Visual Studio to process #includes in .rc files - I'm not having a problem with that.  My .rc's  compile fine - I just have to edit them by hand to add new elements to dialogs, etc.  Do you know of a good free tool that does this?